# "ssh localhost" not working without entering login password on Mac

Tags: ssh

When I fire the command "ssh localhost", I am always getting asked for password.
partha@Parthas-MBP ~ % ssh localhost
(partha@localhost) Password:

I have given proper rights to all files under "~/.ssh/" folder

```
partha@Parthas-MBP ~ % ls -lrt ~/.ssh/*  
-rwxrwxr-x  1 partha  staff  2610 May 15 15:17 /Users/partha/.ssh/id_rsa
-rwxrwxr-x  1 partha  staff   572 May 15 15:17 /Users/partha/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwxr-x  1 partha  staff   572 May 15 15:17 /Users/partha/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rwxrwxr-x  1 partha  staff    91 May 15 15:18 /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts.old
-rwxrwxr-x  1 partha  staff   825 May 15 15:18 /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The complete verbose log is as below.

```
partha@Parthas-MBP ~ % ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.5
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to localhost port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/partha/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'partha'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from localhost
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:vQ9e/Je46T5XXO4ar2I6IeaJHbZ2lQfJkFm/qy85JHc
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from localhost
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/partha/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:97SoRQEsHc2Yixc4X+QfE1c+PKJMpFbE/vjAqjJUNcM
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:97SoRQEsHc2Yixc4X+QfE1c+PKJMpFbE/vjAqjJUNcM
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/partha/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(partha@localhost) Password:
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ssh key you have now and create a new one using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to create a passwordless one

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html